# Date Time Variable and the blank or Null Values in a Date Column

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssis, sql-server-2012

When I have an execute sql task where I have the

```
Select '' AS [CancelledDate] from TableX
```

I map this column to a data time variable called `CancelledDate`, however when I run the `Execute Sql Task` I get this Error:

> Error: 0xC002F309 at Sp Get Parameter for SP2, Execute SQL Task: An error occurred while assigning a value to variable "CancelledDate": "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.".
>   Task failed: Sp Get Parameter for SP2

If I replace the `''` with `'01-JAN-1978'` it works. This must have a problem with `Null` and `''` in the columns.

I tried to put `NULL(DT_DATE)` in the variable and set evaluate as expression to True but that did not work either!

Answer (score 3):

Well, first of all - **empty string** is not the same as **NULL**. NULL (no value) can be "converted" to any type, 'cause each type may be in NULL state while empty string is not *nothing* and it may or may not be successfully converted to the type you need.

Second - column cannot have **no type**. Which type is your column `CancelledDate`? It is `varchar`. I guess, `varchar(1)`. It contains empty string. Is this a valid **datetime**? No.

Always explicitly specify type for such a virtual column. And for logical **NULL** use NULL itself instead of empty string or zero or something else.

Here is sample code that returns **datetime** column with **NULL**:

```
select cast(NULL as datetime) AS [CancelledDate]
from TableX
```

Comment: Also, if you are mapping this to a .Net DateTime struct, you will probably need to use the DateTime? type.